# Positioning sprites inside scene

Tags: position, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skscene

I would like when i create all my sprites to get centred in the screen, but that is not the case, i have a sprite when i set it's position to `CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 2)` it gets centred vertically but not horizontally, when i set it to `CGPointMake(0, 0)` it sets at the bottom of the screen with only half of it's body visible ( which is what you expect) but horizontally it doesn't get positioned right ( half his vertical body appears ) until i set it's X to 300.
How come the sprite's Y position gets set right but the X doesn't ?

```
scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
```

and i haven't set any anchorPoint, 4' screen.

UPDATE:

I'm using Portrait, played around with different scaleMode and found out that the perfect (0, 0) that sets the sprite on the bottom left is:

```
scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
```

It also works fine with different screen sizes,but `(self.size.width / 2)` puts it further to the left.Do you think it's the best setting for all SpriteKit Portrait projects?

Comment: Check scene.scaleMode setting, depending on which it is parts of the scene may be outside the screen due to stretching/scaling. Also, if you create the first scene in viewDidLoad and the app is in landscape mode you won't get the correct size, you need to create the scene in viewWillLayoutSubviews with a (skview.scene == nil) check.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce what you are saying, but I couldn't, either using .sks file or not for loading the [scene](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH3-SW14). Also I've produced good results on both 7.1 and 8.1 simulators...The thing is that simulators sometimes could be tricky and not 100% reliable, so you should not trust them much.

I don't know if this will help you, but you should consider it...In Xcode 5 projects scene is programmatically created to have a size of the view. Basically it's done in [viewDidLoad](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad) method like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    GameScene * scene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

Or using [viewWillLayoutSubviews](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillLayoutSubviews) like LearnCocos2D pointed:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{

    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];


    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
    skView.showsDrawCount = YES;
    //skView.showsQuadCount = YES;

    skView.showsPhysics = YES;
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;

    if(!skView.scene){
        // Create and configure the scene.
        GameScene * scene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];

        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

        // Present the scene.
        [skView presentScene:scene];
    }


}
```

But Xcode 6  uses an SKS file:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
    // Configure the view.
    let skView = self.view as SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true

    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
  }
}
```

If you look at the GameScene.sks you can see that the default scene size is 1024x768.

Try to print your scene size as well as view's bounds size to see actuall sizes. You can use something like:

```
println("view.bounds\(view.bounds), self.size\(self.size)")
```

I don't know if any of this helped, but I hope it will lead you somewhere. Goodluck!

Comment: I added this line and it seemed to help a lot: "scene.size = skView.bounds.size"

Comment: @Abdou023   MyScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:self.view.bounds.size]; is what I have found to be the most accurate way to do it also. You would think frame would be good enough but turns out bounds is what you want as whirlwind has in this answer :)